# Calculus question table leg

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate the volume of the “table leg” for which the radius r at height z is given by the following expression, with $0 \leq z \leq 12 $:

$$r(z)=4+\cos \left( \frac{\pi z}{2} \right)$$

then it says "It may be wise to sketch the graph of the function to be integrated with respect to the interval of interest." which might no useful for this format

so this would have to be a volume of a revolution. where instead of $y$ as a function of $x$ it is $r$ as a function of $z$, so the integral is

$$\pi \int_{0}^{12} 16+\cos^2\left( \frac{\pi z}{2} \right) + 8\cos\left( \frac{\pi z}{2} \right) dz $$

Is this going right? I'm not quite sure how to integrate $\cos^2 \left( \frac{\pi z}{2} \right) $

Comment: For integrating $\cos^2 t$, one way is the double-angle isentity $\cos 2t=2\cos^2 t-1$, rewritten as $\cos^2 t=\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos 2t)$.

Comment: I can't use imaginary numbers

Comment: There are no imaginary numbers involved in my suggested use of the double-angle formula. And the variable $z$ in your expression ranges over real numbers, it has nothing to do with imaginary numbers, it has to do with the $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes in $3$ dimensions.